# Xcode vs TextEdit “Find and Replace…”

Tags: keyboard, xcode, search, textedit

The default hotkey behavior in both Xcode and TextEdit “Find and Replace” is:
Find... <kbd>⌘F</kbd>
Find and Replace... <kbd>⌘⌥F</kbd>

However, in TextEdit, the dialog for “Find and Replace” remains even after you press <kbd>⌘F</kbd>. In Xcode <kbd>⌘F</kbd> hides the “Find and Replace” section of the dialog and only displays the “Find” part.

In TextEdit, <kbd>⌘F</kbd> sets the focus (which means your text marker is in the box) in the “Find” textbox. <kbd>⌘⌥F</kbd> sets the focus in the “Find and Replace” textbox. Pressing <kbd>⌘⌥F</kbd> followed by <kbd>⌘F</kbd> keeps the entire dialog open. In Xcode the focus is ALWAYS in the “Find” dialog, no matter what hotkey you invoked it with.

I prefer the TextEdit behavior, but would also like consistency. Is there any way to make Xcode behave as TextEdit in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Part solution for setting the focus for <kbd>⌘⌥F</kbd>

Save this Applescript down as a **Text** file instead of a script.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "Xcode" to activate
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events"

    tell process "Xcode"

        keystroke "z" using {command down, option down}
        delay 0.3

        keystroke tab
    end tell
end tell
```

In terminal.app

Make the script file executable by running

`chmod  +x /path/to/foo.applescript`

---

In Xcode  go to the Preferences-> Key Bindings Tab.

And change the **Find and Replace (menu)** 's hotkey to **⌘⌥z**

[image]

---

Now still in Preferences go to the **Behaviours** Tab

Click the '+' button to add a new custom Behaviour.

Name it and give it the hotkey **⌘⌥f**

On the right hand pane of the **Behaviours** Tab scroll down to the bottom

And using the **Run**  dropdown **choose script**. Select your Script file.

[image]

Now you can use the <kbd>⌘⌥F</kbd> and the find and replace will appear and focus will go to the replace field.

---

As to replicating the keeping the Replace in view if it is already showing when you hit  <kbd>⌘F</kbd>.  I think that in most cases it is redundant because you will want to still hit <kbd>⌘⌥F</kbd> to get back to the replace field and the Find's text field will still be show with the changes you just made.

Comment: I had no idea you could use scripts like that in Xcode. And I agree on your final point, though it would be nice to have a visual representation of what’s happening without having to always use `⌘⌥F` and subsequently `⇧↹` several times… Your answer suffices for my usage, at least. Thanks a lot!